# Inheriting PyQt5 class

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to follow some [YouTube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9_Om_KPfeg) on how to create GUIs and create a class that inherits a GUI with PyQt. Those tutorials use PyQt4 while I have PyQt5. I have made some changes to not to have referencing errors, but the window doesn't show.

My class:

```
import sys
from ETF.modules.profiles_input.gui import *

class ProfileInput(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_ProfileInputWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = ProfileInput()
    app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My GUI class starts with:
(This code is ok, and I include it just for reference)

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

    class Ui_ProfileInputWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, ProfileInputWindow):
            ProfileInputWindow.setObjectName("ProfileInputWindow")
            ProfileInputWindow.resize(880, 495)
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(ProfileInputWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
            self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
            self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
            self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
            self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
            self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab)
            self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
            self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
            self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
            self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
            self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
            self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
            self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
            self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
            self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab)
            self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)
            self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
            self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
            self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
            self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
            self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
            ProfileInputWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

            self.retranslateUi(ProfileInputWindow)
            self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushButton.click)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ProfileInputWindow)
```

when I execute the first piece of code, the python interpreter just closes with the message:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

What is wrong in the first piece of code?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the problem that you set `app` twice? It should hold the reference to the application, not to the mainwindow. Put that in a separate variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign to `app` twice here:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app = ProfileInput()
app.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code should look like this:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = ProfileInput()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```